# Android XML Layout alignment (button grid)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I've created a group of nested `LinearLayout`s to form a grid of buttons; set the weight of each group and each child in the group, however the alignment just won't come out right.

It doesn't seem right either having so many nested layouts... is there a better way to do this?

Here is an image illustrating my problem:
[image: android xml layout problem]

The code is quite long so I'll just describe the outline:

```
MAIN LINEAR LAYOUT (horizontal)
   Col 1: linear layout (vertical)
          contains two horizontal linear layouts with two buttons each (2x2 grid)
   Col 2: linear layout (vertical)
          contains three horizontal linear layouts with three buttons each (3x3 grid)
   Col 3: linear layout (vertical)
          contains two horizontal linear layouts with two buttons each (2x2 grid)
END MAIN LINEAR LAYOUT
```

As requested [here is the XML code](http://pastebin.com/m7NwTfgP)

Following [@R9j's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17081101/1031312) I've switched to a `RelativeLayout` and made some progress. However there is a floating issue where the `ImageView`s are overlapping. Slight sizing issue too; I need to fit everything into the 4.7" Nexus 4 screen nicely too.

[image: Progress with RelativeLayout]

Comment: could you post your xml?

Comment: @R9j added a link to the XML in my post

Comment: the images you're using for player control (arrows) seem to have a big padding. Are you sure the image has no extra padding? Each of those image should be a square and their dimensions should be equal

Comment: @gunar the images are a square (but bigger than they need to be for higher density screens and scaled down to fit to the button). They are PNGs with transparent background. However I haven't defined any button sizes because I want them to scale upward for larger screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would help you

```
linearlayout (horizontal){
    relative layout(weight = 1){
        image view(alignParentTop=true, alignParentLeft=true)
        image view(alignParentTop=true, alignParentRight=true)
        image view(alignParentBottom=true, alignParentLeft=true)
        image view(alignParentBottom=true, alignParentRight=true)
    }
    relative layout(weight = 1){
        image view(alignParentLeft=true, height=fillParent)
        image view(alignParentRight=true, height=fillParent)
        image view(alignParentTop=true, centerHorizontal=true)
        image view(alignParentBottom=true, centerHorizontal=true)
    }
    relative layout(weight = 1){
        image view(alignParentTop=true, alignParentLeft=true)
        image view(alignParentTop=true, alignParentRight=true)
        image view(alignParentBottom=true, alignParentLeft=true)
        image view(alignParentBottom=true, alignParentRight=true)
    }
}
```

design your xml according the above model.

Comment: it's a lot better, however there's only the issue of all the buttons overlapping. How can I make them rigid?

Comment: create id for all buttons and align it through toLeftOf and toRightOf attributes specified in relative layout.

Comment: Thanks that does work, but to avoid the sizing issue I had to leave the distributed sizes and put in absolute widths and heights for all of my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

It also looks like you could do this in RelativeLayout as well, just have to be a little more careful.

Edit: Post your XML file if you have trouble and if I have the time, I will redo it and post the solution xml.

Comment: I'm looking into the GridLayout, and I've added a link to the XML in my post

Comment: GridLayout is available since API level 14

Comment: @gunar no problem, I'm designing for API 14-17 only